# Convert a dictionary of iterables into an iterator of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a user-editable dictionary of content used to fill in a `string.Template` and I wanted to allow the user to fill the same template with several values at once.

Using only values, `itertools.product` would be enough for my needs but I needed dictionaries to fill in a template. I also wanted users to be able to enter a single string or numerical value as values for the dictionary without having anything blowing up and requiring them to encapsulate their single value in a 1-length tuple.

I used `itertools.product(*map(pair_iter_safe, <the_dict>.items()))` to generate iterables of key-value pairs suitable for the `dict()` constructor or the `dict.update()` method. With `pair_iter_safe` being:

```
def pair_iter_safe(kv_pair):
    key, value = kv_pair
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = (value,)
    else:
        try:
            value = iter(value)
        except TypeError:
            value = (value,)

    for val in value:
        yield key, val
```

For a broader picture here is a simplified example of calling code:

```
import sys
import string
import itertools


PARAMETERS = {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'age': range(40,45),
    'activity': ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'),
}


SCENARIO = """\
[@campaign] @name:
    Hi! I'm @age and I like to @activity.
"""


class AtTemplate(string.Template):
    delimiter = '@'


def run_scenario(parameters, stdout):
    scenario = AtTemplate(SCENARIO).substitute(parameters)
    print(scenario, file=stdout)


def run_campaign(campaign_name='test', stdout=sys.stdout):
    parameters = {'campaign': campaign_name}
    for setup in itertools.product(*map(pair_iter_safe, PARAMETERS.items())):
        parameters.update(setup)
        run_scenario(parameters, stdout)


def pair_iter_safe(kv_pair):
    key, value = kv_pair
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = (value,)
    else:
        try:
            value = iter(value)
        except TypeError:
            value = (value,)

    for val in value:
        yield key, val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_campaign()
```

Is there anything wrong with the approach or the `pair_iter_safe` function altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

I decided to look only at `itertools.product(*map(pair_iter_safe, <the_dict>.items()))` and `pair_iter_safe`.

The way I look at it is from a theoretic memory usage perspective. Due to how you have defined it, all `(key, value)` pairs need to be in memory at the same time, which could take a bit of memory.

I would suggest the following:

```
def iter_safe(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = (value,)
    try:
        iter(value)
    except TypeError:
        return (value,)
    else:
        return value
```

And using it as follows:

```
def dict_combinations(d):
    keys, values_list = zip(*d.items())
    for values in itertools.product(*map(iter_safe, values_list)):
        yield dict(zip(keys, values))
```

To me this is cleaner, having separated out the `iter_safe` logic from the dicts.

Though merely theoretical, I think this should save on memory usage due to there not being as much key-value pairs in memory all the time.

Of course, if you still want `pair_iter_safe`, you should be able to do something like

```
def pair_iter_safe(kv_pair):
    key, value = kv_pair
    for v in iter_safe(value):
        yield key, v
```

Comment: I might end up only yielding `zip(keys, values)` to feed into `dict.update` but other than that, great answer. It is much closer to what I had in mind in the first place, I just forgot that `zip` is its own reflection.

Comment: Changed `basestring` to `str`. Maybe `(str, bytes)` would be appropriate as well?

Comment: In the initial version I wrote I also used a loop instead of `zip(*...)`. It's so easy to forget that I'd rather have it be called `unzip` instead.

Comment: `bytes` won't be an issue in my use cases, but its worth noting if anyone have similar needs.