# Product of dictionary values

Tags: python, hash-map

Elements that smell funny: argument unpacking to `itertools.product`. I'm needing sorted keys (even though I don't care about key order in the final result).

```
"""
>>> d = {'A': [0, 1, 2],
...      'B': [3, 4],
...      'C': [5, 6, 7]}
>>> for element in dict_product(d):
...     print(element)
{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}
{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 6}
{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 7}
{'A': 0, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}
{'A': 0, 'B': 4, 'C': 6}
{'A': 0, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}
{'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 6}
{'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 6}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 6}
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 6}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}

"""

from itertools import product

def dict_product(d):
    sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys())
    for element in product(*list(d[k] for k in sorted_keys)):
        yield dict(zip(sorted_keys, element))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Comment: I had the [same need](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128088/convert-a-dictionary-of-iterables-into-an-iterator-of-dictionaries) a while back.

Comment: `map(dict, product(*[[(k, v) for v in vv] for k, vv in d.items()]))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the fact that `d.keys()` and `d.values()` are always aligned. This gets rid of both the awkward way of constructing the values as well as the sorting of the keys.

```
def dict_product(d):
    keys = d.keys()
    for element in product(*d.values()):
        yield dict(zip(keys, element))
```

The assignment of `keys` is not strictly necessary, but it avoids the look-up every loop iteration.

---

Note that `list(d[k] for k in sorted_keys)` should have been written as a list comprehension directly, instead of calling `list` on a generator comprehension. So `[d[k] for k in sorted_keys]`.

---

Your `doctest` might fail in Python 2 or in Python implementations other than cPython. This is because only recently have dictionary keys become ordered (by insertion time) in (c)Python 3. This is still an implementation detail and not something you should rely upon. Since `doctest` performs a string comparison, it does not notice that the objects are actually the same.

The only way around this, at least the only one I can see, is to use a more sophisticated testing framework, like `unittest`. This comes with more code overhead, though.

Comment: And if you are going to invest in something like unittest, go straight to pytest.  Better in basically every way.

Comment: To make this work with `doctest`, one can (a) [use `OrderedDict` on input and `pprint` (which sorts dictionaries) on output](http://goo.gl/44A7WT) or (b) [somewhat awkwardly construct a set of frozensets and compare it to an expected value](http://goo.gl/gfJsJg).